# Code Coverage on sonar Dashboard

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, code-coverage

I am not able to see code coverage on sonar dashboard.

I am able to see below line in jenkins log:
[JaCoCo plugin] Overall coverage: class: 11, method: 5, line: 9, branch: 3, instruction: 7

Could you help me on this ?

Comment: Do you run the sonar goal or plugin?

Comment: How are you uploading the jacoco result to sonar?

Comment: using goal in jenkins :

Comment: clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true